# Possible to use spl_autoload_register from object?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

Simple question but I don't know if this is really possible..

Example:

class test has a spl_autoload_register like this:

```
function __construct() {
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        echo "{$this->projectroot}/include/{$class}.php";
        require_once(strtolower("{$this->projectroot}/classes/{$class}.php"));
});
}
```

$projectroot is an object scope variable with the path to the project's directory.

I include class test in my project, create a new instance out of it:

```
$test = new test();
```

Now I want $test to load a class file with functions when I create:

```
$test2 = new test2();
```

where test2 is the class in /include/test2.php called test2.

when I try to do this, it gives me an error saying:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
```

but when I try:

```
$test2 = new $test1->test2();
```

it ignores the spl_autoload_register function in test1 completely :/ just stating that obviously test2 isn't a known method (undefined property).

Is there a way to use the spl_autoload_register function in class test in my project without further defining it in my main project?

**EDIT**

I "fixed" it using a global variable, but I am curious if there's some OOP method? (Not that this is practical/best practise OOP use...) just curious.

Comment: If you load your files in __constructor, then there is no need for spl_autoload; just require files and that is it...

Comment: @ Glavic, you're absolutely right. Problem is I will use this class in different projects which have all together completely different needs. So project a will have classes which I will never use in project b, or c. Therefor I want to be able to just dump new class files in the include folder and not worry about including them manualy each time I start a new project.

Comment: Are you using `PHP >= 5.4` ?

Comment: At this point in life I use 5.3.3

Comment: I "fixed" it using a global variable, but I am curious if there's some OOP method? (Not that this is practical/best practise OOP use...) just curious.

Comment: Removed my answer because it wasn't good. Will dig into this

Comment: In PHP 5.4 you can use `$this` inside closures like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can register any callable object as a parameter.

```
spl_autoload_register( array( $object, 'public function name'));

spl_autoload_register( 'classname::static_method');
```

Should help.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from reactions to the question: In PHP 5.4 you can use $this inside closures like that.

This is probably the answer.